# Subqueries in multiple WHERE statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Place
-id
-latitude
-longitude

Event
-id
-user_id
-latitude
-longitude
-radius
```

I need to have as an output the list of user_id who has been in a place. I am not sure I can do it using a subquery as I have to check two parameters at the same time: latitude(+- radius) and longitude(+- radius).

Admitting that the radius is always 1 to simplify the problem, it gives this query:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE 
latitude > (SELECT latitude-1 FROM place) AND
latitude < (SELECT latitude+1 FROM place) AND
longitude > (SELECT longitude-1 FROM place) AND
longitude < (SELECT latitude+1 FROM place)
```

Which fails because a subquery cannot return more than one row. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: @Siyual I agree. I will try and come back with the firsts results. I was a bit lazy on this one.

Comment: I have added the query.

Comment: Where is "precision" stored?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "radius". It is now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply (I should put scare quotes around that as I don't have MySQL or data to test this...)

```
select distinct
    place.id,
    user_id
from
    event
    inner join place on
        event.latitude between
            place.latitude - event.radius
            and place.latitude + event.radius
        and event.latitude between
            place.longitude - event.radius
            and place.longitude + event.radius;
```